# Ошибка при использовании IoC-контейнера Unity

Tags: c#

Пробую работать с IoC-контейнером Unity, установил через nuget, и получаю такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В references
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Ваш проект использует .net framework версии ниже 4.5, например, 4.0.

Вы можете поменять версию .net framework, используемую в проекте, в настройке проекта на вкладке Application, в разделе Target framework.

Или же, Вы можете взять более старую версию Unity, например, 2 версию. Выбрать более старую версию можно так же через NuGet.